# Regression analysis results not coming in Range of numbers expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to conduct Regression analysis on 25-D data.
My data is in a data frame.
My end objective to predict a score value which is a percentage (0,99,70,22 e.t.c)

1.Do i need to normalize the data/scale it or Linear/Polynomial Regression analysis handles this?

2. I applied Polynomial Regression though it gives me a good r squared value what i see id that it returns results in negative values -342.54 else high range values like 252 (not at all in range of scores i gave to train) How do i rectify this ?
   Is there any other technique i want to predict values?
   So heres the link data type:
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1swkRwLXklrWEDV3bKic5uxl_uHLjzU0QDHJ2JLSP8zQ/edit?usp=sharing

Also here's the code:

```
 X= colum[D:AC] of spreadsheet
Y= column['Score'] or column ['Match'] in case of logistic regression
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
X_test_ = poly.fit_transform(X_test)
# Instantiate
lg = LinearRegression()

   # Fit
  lg.fit(X_, y)

 # Obtain coefficients
 lg.coef_
```

Comment: Without your code and data, we cant do anything.

Comment: @vivek kumar gave a sample tuple and code please help with any changes to be made in code/ approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.Do i need to normalize the data/scale it or Linear/Polynomial Regression analysis handles this?**

It is "usually" a good practice. Model converges faster. If you are using `sklearn`, then the [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) module has a parameter called `normalize` which when set to `True` will normalize all variables before fitting the model

**2. I applied Polynomial Regression though it gives me a good r squared value what i see id that it returns results in negative values -342.54 else high range values like 252 (not at all in range of scores i gave to train) How do i rectify this ? Is there any other technique i want to predict values?**

Polynomial Regression is designed to give values between `-inf` and `+inf`. If you want percentage values, scale these variables through a function like `sigmoid`. You can also use `Logistic Regression` and the `predict_proba()` function will output probabilities between 0 and 1 (although this model works on a different objective entirely).

As @VivekKumar rightly said, we can hardly help you unless we have specific information.

Comment: @ vivekKumar thanks a simple doubt does do reg.coeff_ values add to 1 in case of linear regression?

Comment: No they dont. They are unitless weights which are not bound by that constraint

Comment: Thanks a ton! Have given my sample tuple and code could you please help me with a link/ code as to how to implement sigmoid for polynomial Regression. Tried normalizing the data for linear regression but the Rsquared value of the model is still bad no luck?